# Get last N elements for each item of a JSON object

Tags: json, object, key, jq

Given the following JSON object, using jq, how to get the last two elements for each item?

I have been trying to find a solution with the help of jqplay.org but didn't get anywhere. While getting values out of objects having consistent key names is rather straightforward, I can't get my head around this.

Input:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "abc": { "key1": "value1" }, 
    "bcd": { "key1": "value1" },
    "cde": { "key1": "value1" },
    "def": { "key1": "value1" }, 
    "efg": { "key1": "value1" },
    "fgh": { "key1": "value1" }
  }, 
  "bar": {
    "ghi": { "key1": "value1" }
  }, 
  "qux": {
    "hij": { "key1": "value1" }, 
    "ijk": { "key1": "value1" },
    "jkl": { "key1": "value1" },
    "klm": { "key1": "value1" }
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "efg": { "key1": "value1" },
    "fgh": { "key1": "value1" }
  }, 
  "bar": {
    "ghi": { "key1": "value1" }
  }, 
  "qux": {
    "jkl": { "key1": "value1" },
    "klm": { "key1": "value1" }
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Feel free to elaborate, I would be curious to see alternative methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to delete all fields but the last N (2 here) using `delpaths`. You need to convert key names to path representations though. E.g:

```
map_values(delpaths(keys_unsorted[:-2] | map([.])))
```

See the [jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hy_hYj6oN9).

Comment: Brilliant! Could you please explain the various parts?

Comment: what do you mean *various parts*?

Comment: what does [.] do?
what does map ([.]) do?
etc.

Correct me if I am wrong: [.] turns an obj into an array, map([.]) turns the items into an array. From there, for instance, I don't get why keys_unsorted is piped to map rather than the other way around. That's the same for the previous commands, everything seems backward. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: refer to jq man page, type `man jq` to your terminal for that

Comment: `man jq` probably won't be helpful.  A pointer to the online documentation is given by `jq --help`.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward and efficient solution:

```
map_values( to_entries[-2:] | from_entries)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works as well. Same question than for @oguz-ismail though, could you please explain the various parts? Or, in other words, how does it produces the desired output, except for the [-2:] that defines a range, the rest looks like black magic to me. I would rather be taught how to fish than be given a fish ;)

Comment: With the jq manual in hand, you'll find it easy to figure out the other three components of the solution, but you might also find it helpful to sprinkle a `debug` or two in the pipeline.