# how to get the last 3 elements with specific name value with JMESPATH and javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, jmespath

I have the below json data array:

```
[{"name":"Button1","date":"1596959802144"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1596959804238"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1596959809334"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597000878135"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000896335"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597000901536"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000904437"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597000909535"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597000912250"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000939937"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597000957940"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000964640"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597001005141"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001010240"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001014845"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001021644"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597001025738"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001049030"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001054139"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597001057741"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001060340"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001062445"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002599045"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002604128"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002609546"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002613435"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002681736"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002690843"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002694136"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002696349"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002699243"}]
```

and I would like to use JMESPath javascript library to get only the last 3 entries per each distinct name value. For example:

```
[{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001014845"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001021644"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001049030"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001054139"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001060340"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001062445"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002694136"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002696349"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002699243"}]
```

So the last 3 occurrences fro each name = Button*

checking on stackOverflow and I saw that with JQ is possible to do using this function: `map_values(delpaths(keys_unsorted[:-2] | map([.])))`

[Get last N elements for each item of a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181874/get-last-n-elements-for-each-item-of-a-json-object)

Is there any way to do? or using other javascript module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the order in your resulting array, here would be a pure JavaScript way to do this:

```js
const getLastNForEveryName = (arr, n) => {
  const lastNOfEach = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(acc[curr.name] == null) { // If the key doesnt exist yet, create it with the current item in the array
      acc[curr.name] = [curr]; 
    } else {
      if(acc[curr.name].length >= n) // If the array is as big as the desired size alread, remove the first added one
        acc[curr.name].shift();

      acc[curr.name].push(curr); // push the current item in the array
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
  
  return Object.values(lastNOfEach).flatMap(l => l); // Just get the values of the object and flatMap it, so that we dont have arrays of arrays
}



// Testing
const values = [{"name":"Button1","date":"1596959802144"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1596959804238"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1596959809334"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597000878135"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000896335"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597000901536"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000904437"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597000909535"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597000912250"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000939937"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597000957940"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597000964640"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597001005141"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001010240"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001014845"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001021644"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597001025738"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001049030"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001054139"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597001057741"},{"name":"Button2","date":"1597001060340"},{"name":"Button3","date":"1597001062445"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002599045"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002604128"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002609546"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002613435"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002681736"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002690843"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002694136"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002696349"},{"name":"Button1","date":"1597002699243"}];

console.log(getLastNForEveryName(values, 3));
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help @MattVegas

Comment: Thanks need to find the way to have it on complex way,  having an array of values per each name in dinamicaly way. Array of hash map, each array all values and key of hash with the name of button...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me @MattVegas

Comment: This answer does not use JMESPATH as specified in the question.

Comment: @YvesGurcan He specifically stated "or using other javascript module". Therefore, I assumed he was okay with using anything, other than jQuery. Why use some library, if you can easily use JavaScript to do the same.